# How to compare cookie domain and NSURL?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just want to get access token from cookies, in if condition I want to compare cookie domain and given `URL`. I'm trying with the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:websiteUrl];

    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [webView loadRequest:requestObj];  
}

- (NSString*)getTokenFromCookie {

    NSHTTPCookie *cookie;

    NSHTTPCookieStorage *cookieJar = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

    for (cookie in [cookieJar cookies]) {

        NSLog(@"%@",cookie);

        //Here to compare cookie domain and above given URL

        if ([[cookie domain] isEqualToString:domain]) {

            if ([[cookie name] isEqualToString:@"oauth_token"]) {

                return [cookie value];
            }
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have? Is there an error, or you're just not getting the result you expect?

Comment: Not getting an error,but the condition fails to return nil